# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ email: 'dddd@gmail.com' }" (type Object) at path "_id" for model "User"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose

I should be, how to utilize mongoose id for fetching data for sending to client of browser?
***my mogooseDb data:***
{"_id":{"$oid":"6404fc0b9e6a0640b0deb716"},"username":"dddd","email":"dddd@gmail.com","password":"dddd@123","confirmpassword":"dddd@123","createdAt":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1678048268046"}},"updatedAt":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1678048268046"}},"__v":{"$numberInt":"0"}}

```js
Res:=>
{[0] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[0] [nodemon] starting `node server.js`
[0] Server running...
[0] DB Connection established
[0] _id undefined
[0] exist null
```

I am using mongooseBb,I did't get method data, can you make please for this question solution

```js
app.get('/myprofile',middleware,async(req, res)=>{
    try{
          const {_id} = req.query;
         let exist = await user.findById(_id);
        console.log("_id",_id)
        console.log("exist",exist)
        if(!exist){
            return res.status(400).send('User not found');
        }
        res.json(exist);
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).send('Server Error')
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you are passing _id in api url.while printing the value of _id.It is undefined.
And Your api url should be like this: .../myprofile?_id=342837432